# How to serialize objects together with byte array into a file?

Tags: java, serialization, objectoutputstream, bytearrayoutputstream

I have a java class that contains an inner class and a byte array member, for example `KeyValPair hdr` and `byte[] content`, and I'd like to serialize only the inner class `hdr` and the byte array `content`, rather than the whole class instance as there are some other unneccesary fields in the class.

I know how to serialize objects using `ObjectOutputStream`, and I know how to convert an object into a byte array, but I'm not sure whether I can store them at the same time without converting the inner class instance`KeyValPair hdr` into byte array. If I convert it into byte array and store it together with `content`, how do I know the length of `hdr` when deserializing it from file?

Another question is that is it possible to use `MappedBytesBuffer` together with `ObjectOutputStream` or something like `ByteArrayOutputStream`? Because I'm in a scene that requires certain level of performance for I/O and the process might be killed... so is it a good idea to use `MappedBytesBuffer`?

I'm a newbie to java, so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just serialize the byte array *as an object,* with `writeObject()` and deserialize with `readObject()`. That will take care of the length automatically.

Comment: Thanks, it is able to run now, but the content seems not right with `readObject()`. The content of the inner class is right, but not the byte array. I read it with `content = (byte[])ois.readObject();` and the result is like such strings `[B@46c603e9`. Did miss anything?

Comment: Yes, you missed examining the content. The string you mention is just the result of `toString()`. It isn't the content.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I did forget about that. It seems that creating a new String instance would solve the problem.